# Java: optimization of method ran every 10 microseconds

Tags: java, optimization, timer, raspberry-pi

**EDIT: I did some `println()`ing with `nanoTime()` and found that `stepPins[pin].toggle()` takes 4226 microseconds. Now I need to find a faster way of switching pins.**

I am making a program to control a musical floppy drive array. At the moment I have a method running every 10 microseconds and ticking the necessary floppies by reading a short, in the form 01001011 where 1=tick floppy (there are 8 floppies).

The code, for some reason, runs way too slow causing the note frequencies to be way off.

Here is the method and its class:

```
public class Timer implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int i = Main.currentSteps.get(Main.time);
        try
        {
            if (Main.time > Main.maxTime)
            {
                Main.executor.remove(Main.timer);
                FloppyController.resetAll();
            }
            if ((i & 1) == 1)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(0);
            }
            if ((i & 2) == 2)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(1);
            }
            if ((i & 4) == 4)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(2);
            }
            if ((i & 8) == 8)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(3);
            }
            if ((i & 16) == 16)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(4);
            }
            if ((i & 32) == 32)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(5);
            }
            if ((i & 64) == 64)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(6);
            }
            if ((i & 128) == 128)
            {
                FloppyController.stepPin(7);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        Main.time++;
    }
}
```

and for what it's worth, the relevant part of my `Main.java` class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static ArrayList<Short> currentSteps;
    public static ArrayList<Note> all = new ArrayList<Note>();
    public static long maxTime = 0;
    public static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    public static Timer timer;

    public static int time;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvalidMidiDataException, IOException, MidiUnavailableException
    {
        //initialize
        FloppyController.init();
        currentSteps = new ArrayList<Short>();
        FloppyController.resetAll();

        for (int o = 0; o < Math.ceil(maxTime / 10); o++)
        {
            currentSteps.add((short) 0);
        }

        //populate list
        for (Note n : all)
        {
            for (int a = Math.round(n.timeStart / 10); a <= Math.round(n.timeEnd / 10); a += n.wait)
            {
                currentSteps.set(a, (short) (currentSteps.get(a) + (((currentSteps.get(a) & (short) Math.pow(2, n.channel)) == Math.pow(2, n.channel)) ? 0 : Math.pow(2, n.channel))));
            }
        }

        //start play executions
        executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        long resolution = 10; //# of microsecond iterations
        timer = new Timer();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 0, resolution, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    }
```

How can I optimize the `run()` method of `Timer.class`?

I am also considering changing the `currentSteps` ArrayList to a HashMap and only including the non zero values with their corresponding time as the key as I am running into memory issues on the Raspberry Pi I am running this on.

Here is the `stepPin` method:

```
public static void stepPin(int pin) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (pinPositions[pin] >= 79)
        {
            changeDirection(pin, true);
        }
        else if(pinPositions[pin] < 0)
        {
            changeDirection(pin, false);
        }
        stepPins[pin].toggle();
        stepPins[pin].toggle();
        pinPositions[pin] += pinDirections[pin].isLow() ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Comment: Does `stepPin` blocks (until the floppy has produced its sound)?

Comment: Will add method to main question, might be a good idea to schedule and not run `stepPin()`

Comment: Timer is not exact, it will try to do its best to run every x ms but that is subject to the underlying system.

Comment: @TT. is there a better alternative? At least it is better than Thread.sleep :P

Comment: I would suggest scheduling in less than 10 ms (eg 8 or 9 ms depending on accuracy of system) and peeking the time (eg System.nanoTime()) in a loop. It's dirty but it might give you better resolution. GL!

Comment: Note that println() also has an overhead, and console IO in Java is traditionally slow. I recommend writing to a buffered file instead.

Comment: I assume that rewriting the whole thing in C is out of the question? For time-sensitive applications, C is much more predictable than Java. In particular, GC can happen at any time.

Comment: 4.2ms to switch a pin... Did you implement this pin-switching functionality yourself or are you using a library to do this? In any case, I think your question has evolved into a different question...

Comment: And what tucuxi sais is right on point... I would never consider JAVA as a language/environment for timing-sensitive applications.

Comment: I was thinking about going to C, but truth is I know nothing about it so I would have to learn it first. On my TODO list, but for now I'm going to try with Java. Also, I am using Pi4J, but will have to go for something else like framboos or something like wiringPi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest launching 1 thread per floppy drive, and using two byte arrays as buffers (lets call them "A" and "B") to schedule sound. The buffers should be large enough for a few seconds' music. The pseudocode would go like this:

- Initialization: fill the A buffer with the first seconds of music. Launch all floppy threads reading from the A buffer.
- Main thread: fill all B buffers with the next seconds of music. Wait until floppy threads reach the B buffers (by elapsed time). Then write the A buffers, and so on until music score exhausted.
- Floppy threads: read current buffer, either using busy waiting (high-definition, high CPU usage) or using the "precise" version of [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long,%20int)) (OS-dependent definition, low CPU usage). Keep in sync with others via System.nanoTime(). When the A buffer is exhausted, switch to B buffer.

Assuming that `stepPin` is blocking, but only blocks its thread, this will isolate your threads from those delays.

Comment: Can I do multiple threads? Remember, I am on a Raspberry Pi. Only 1 core. Will it even make a difference if I run multiple Java processes?

Comment: You can most certainly launch several threads - and if the problem is blocking IO, they should be worth their overhead if time-to-context-switch < time-to-block-for-io. Busy waiting will however be a bad idea.